# Is a square a semi-algebraic set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

Consider the square $[-1,1]^2$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Is this set semi-algebraic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For instance, it may be written as $$\{-x_1+1>0\land x_1+1>0\land -x_2+1>0\land x_2+1>0\}\cup \\ \cup\{x_1+1=0\land x_2+1>0\land -x_2+1>0\}\cup\\\cup \{x_1-1=0\land x_2+1>0\land -x_2+1>0\}\cup\\\cup\{x_2+1=0\land x_1+1>0\land -x_1+1>0\}\cup\\ \cup\{x_2-1=0\land x_1+1>0\land -x_1+1>0\}\cup\\\cup \{x_1+1=0\land x_2+1=0\}\cup\\ \cup \{x_1-1=0\land x_2+1=0\}\cup\\\cup \{x_1+1=0\land x_2-1=0\}\cup\\\cup \{x_1-1=0\land x_2-1=0\}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that you are considering the square $[-1,1]^2$. However, I will simply adapt my question. :)

Comment: @Niklas It would have been more accurate to ask me to change my post, because others might have been in the process of writing their own answer and because it's up to the answerer to be correct. However, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While Gae. S.'s answer is complete and correct, I think you might be able to learn a little more about semialgebraic sets with this question.

Here are a list of basic properties of semialgebraic sets:

> Any algebraic set (zero of any collection of polynomials) is semialgebraic.
>
> The semialgebraic subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ form a Boolean algebra of the powerset of $\Bbb R^n$ (they're closed under complements, finite unions, and finite intersections).
>
> The product of semialgebraic sets $A\subset \Bbb R^n$ and $B\subset \Bbb R^m$ is a semialgebraic subset $A\times B\subset \Bbb R^{n+m}$.
>
> For the projection $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$, the image of any semialgebraic subset is again semialgebraic.

Let's use these to build some intermediate results and some intuition that make this a little easier to understand.

Lemma 1: Any subset $\{x\in\Bbb R^n \mid f(x) > 0\}$ where $f$ is a polynomial is semialgebraic.

Proof: If $f(x)> 0$, then there is a $t\in\Bbb R$ so that $f(x)t^2=1$. So  $\{x\in\Bbb R^n \mid f(x) > 0\}$ is the projection of $\{(x,t)\in\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R \mid f(x)t^2 =1\}$.

Corollary: For any polynomial $f$, any subset $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid f(x)\   ?\   c\}$ where $?$ is any one of $>,\geq,\leq, <$ is semialgebraic.

Proof: To interchange $\leq$ or $<$ and $\geq$ or $>$, swap $f$ for $-f$. To get to $\geq$ from $>$, take the union of $\{x\in\Bbb R^n \mid f(x) > 0\}$ with $\{x\in\Bbb R^n \mid f(x) = 0\}$.

Corollary: $\{x\in\Bbb R^n \mid a \leq f(x) \leq b\}$ is semialgebraic for any real numbers $a,b$.

Proof: Apply the previous corollary, adjusting $f$ as necessary.

These results imply that your square is semialgebraic in several different ways.

Proof 1: $[-1,1]^2\subset \Bbb R^2 = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid -1\leq x\leq 1\}\cap \{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid -1\leq y\leq 1\}$.

Proof 2: $[-1,1]^2\subset \Bbb R^2 = \{x \in\Bbb R\mid -1\leq x\leq 1\}\times\{x \in\Bbb R\mid -1\leq x\leq 1\}$

etc...

I hope this helps you develop better intuition for when you can write things as semialgebraic sets. For futher reading, I like [Michel Coste's notes](http://gcomte.perso.math.cnrs.fr/M2/CosteIntroToSemialGeo.pdf) and [this paper](https://www.journalofsing.org/volume13/denkowska-denkowski.pdf) of Denkowska and Denkowski.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful!